# Is a Gigabyte X79-UP4 compatible with a GeForce GTX 1080?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have a Gigabyte X79-UP4 motherboard and am trying to use it with an EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 FTW ACX 3.0.

My PC meets the power (Corsair CX850M) and system requirements for the card, however, my display cannot find a signal after passing the BIOS screen.

I can use another card to get a display (because I do not have integrated graphics on my i7-3820).

Windows tells me in Device Manager that, "This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)."

My GeForce GTX 970 works fine on the same slot. Do I need to upgrade my motherboard in order to get it to work?

Comment: The Gigabzte X79-UP4 mainboard is at total disaster, thats why you can get it cheap on EBay. It has huge problems with most powerful graphic cards and Gigabyte never tried to fix it. For example the famous boot loop (search it) caused by too modern graphic cards. Only way i got it to boot was with an older GT740 card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your problem is, it's not a compatibility problem between the motherboard and the graphics card.

The most likely explanation is a power problem. Your power supply should definitely be able to handle this though. I would suggest making sure the power connector is the correct type and solidly connected.

The second most likely explanation is a bogus driver that is hogging resources. Try removing any hidden "Mother Board Resources" devices from the device manager (under system devices). Removing any 3GIO adapters may help too. If the system crashes when you remove these devices, just reboot it. The automatic detection after a reboot should fix the issue.

Comment: For my power supply, I am using 4 6-pin connectors with the adapters EVGA provided to convert 4 6-pin connectors into 2 8-pin connectors. Should I try it without the adapters? I also used DDU to uninstall all display drivers, but that didn't work.

Comment: Your problem isn't a driver problem but DDU is still shovelware

Comment: I do not see any stand-out drivers in System Devices.

Comment: Try the procedure I suggested. Uninstall the video drivers, remove any hidden "Motherboard Resources". Remove an 3GIO adapters. Reboot. The adapters should be okay, but I'd prefer using 8-pin connectors that came with your power supply if you have them.